# How was Emil Blonsky able to talk so well as Abomination?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, the-incredible-hulk, marvel, the-incredible-hulk-2008

Bruce Banner took a long time to control Hulk, and Hulk is still not able to do serious talkings.

In *The Incredible Hulk*, Abomination was formed by an overload of Hulk's blood. How was Abomination able to talk consciously the first time Blonsky changed into him?

Is this an example of terrific writing, or do the comics explain something?

Comment: HULK DO SERIOUS TALKINGS

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Any example other than *Hulk Smash* and *Puny God*?

Comment: IN DELETED AVENGERS SCENE HULK TELL BLACK WIDOW SHE NEED TO SETTLE DOWN FIND GOOD MAN BEFORE SHE BECOME OLD BARREN MAID

Comment: @PaulD.Waite That's why it was deleted. And, what's with the CAPITAL COMMENTS...

Comment: HULK BROKE CAPS LOCK KEY :(

Answer (score 6):

I believe this actually figures in with Bruce's explanation in *The Avengers* about always being angry.

Until the battle against Abomination, Bruce has always been fighting *against* The Hulk - trying to restrain him mentally. Once Bruce grudgingly accepts that The Hulk is a part of him, and decides to use his abilities as the Hulk, he has much more control over him. He can now concentrate on attacking just Abomination, or just attacking Loki and the Chitauri.

Blonsky, on the other hand, was specifically seeking Abomination and the power right from the get-go. He wasn't trying to control Abomination, to the contrary, he was specifically trying to make him stronger. By embracing Abomination, he achieves a greater degree of control quicker than Bruce had.

It should also be noted that Abomination and The Hulk were created in two *dramatically* different methods.

The Hulk was created in an accident with gamma radiation.

Abomination was created via a combination of old Super Soldier serum and Banner's blood. While both resulted in giant rage beasts, it is not entirely fair to do a straight comparison between the two and expect them to be identical in all regards.

Comment: Nice theory, but Hulk still can't talk like him.

Comment: @SachinShekhar: so your question is specifically about Abomination being able to talk? I’ve edited your title to actually state that.

Comment: The fact that he doesn't on screen does not mean that he can't.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Talking is an example. There are many other things.

Comment: @phantom42 On Helicarrier, Hulk wasn't even able to understand anyone.

Comment: @phantom42 Might be worth mentioning how Abominations power comes from pure radiation(IIRC) and hulks is from pure anger. Much easier to talk when you are not in a fit of rage.

Comment: @SachinShekhar: “Talking is an example” — of being in control?